# Protocol buffer net with windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm trying to download a response from a server wich is in Protocol Buffer format from a Windows Phone 7 application.

I'm trying to do this with a WebClient, my problem is the following.

The WebClient has only two method for downloading

```
DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
```

and

```
OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url));
```

but this two method are not good to retrieve the response because, the response size should have 16 hexadecimal caracteres    ( 080118CBDDF0E104 ), but the size of the string and the stream get by the two methods are only 8.

So I'm searching a way to resolve my problem.
I found one for C#

```
public static T DownloadProto<T>(this WebClient client, string address)
{
   byte[] data = client.DownloadData(address);
   using (var ms = new MemoryStream(data))
   {
      return Serializer.Deserialize<T>(ms);
   }
}
```

on 
http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/BasicHttp/HttpClient/ProtoWebClient.cs?spec=svn340&r=340

But this method was deleted or not yet implemented on the Windows Phone 7 development kit.

Comment: Indeed; I simply haven't had time to look at the socket/etc side of things for "v2", and it is v2 that works on Phone 7. However, the real question here is: what data comes down the wire? If you have an small but complete example I can play with I might well be able to use it to help finish off this area...

Comment: However; the main issue here *seems* to be getting the complete fragment to the client - that should be unrelated to the actual serialization engine...?

Answer (score 0):

How are you reading from the stream?

If you are reading it as a string then its perhaps reading two bytes per character - instead use

```
var buf = new byte[16];
var actual = stream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
```